# Gatsby Head API, Error, 'Head is not defined'

Tags: javascript, gatsby, server-side-rendering

Having trouble with the new Gatsby Head API (using Gatsby version: 4.21.1).

Hello world code in `/src/pages/index.js`:

```
const Index = () => <div>Hello World</div>

export default Index;

export function Head() {
  return (
    <title>Hello World</title>
  )
}
```

Getting the following frontend error:

[image: Error]

Does anyone know what is causing this ?

The official documentation is listed [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-head/).

Comment: Silly question: have you check the lock version?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error.
Changing extension .js to .jsx in the page folder
It works for me

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the file extension is important for solving this issue.

Try something like this:

```
export const Head = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <title>Hello World</title>
    </>
  );
}
```

You can find a short blog post about the Head API [here](https://datawookie.dev/blog/2024/01/humble-head/).